# Remove width="" and height="" from product images

Tags: magento2, product-images, image

I would like to remove width="" and height="" from my product images in Magento 2. I found in list.phtml the php img tag:

```
<?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
```

I already know how to control the sizes of the images in view.xml. But I want to remove the width and height tags from the IMG.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can change image height and width.

Comment: I already know how to control the sizes of the images in view.xml. But I want to remove the width and height tags from the IMG.

Answer (score 2):

The default image template on product listing page is one of the following files depending on your configuration:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image.phtml
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml
```

You can overwrite them in your theme.